# Air-core gauge driver

Tags: automotive, gauge

My job is to redesign an existing product driving two gauges, currently based on PIC and obsolete Phillips SA5777A air-core gauge driver. I am free to make the design from scratch, but cannot change the two gauges, which are each 4-pin gearless two-coil design with sin+/- and cos+/- pins.

I have browsed the web for many hours for up-to-date and available chip solution, and found only one, Melexis MLX10407. I often base my decisions on stock available at DigiKey, and this Melexis stock is very limited.

My question is, can anyone suggest good source of information how to design this WITHOUT the Melexis chip, using parts which are good for new design?

I do not mind to do it directly from microprocessor, or using external chip (simpler for me). My design time-frame available for both hardware and firmware is 2 months, so I rather spend extra $4 per product then time writing software.

Thank you for your advice, especially if you are already experienced designing air-core gauge drivers.

Comment: Low stock at digi-key is NOT a measure of availability. It can simply mean they do not expect to sell many so only keep a limited stock. Also, quite often DigiKey has a huge stock of Obsolete components.  You are better to check manufacturer for product life status.

Comment: Trevor: true, I did that yesterday. With DigiKey you are correct, i meant to say when they have a huge stock I feel more comfortable. Right now other companies do not even have a stock, even manufacturer, so I thought to look at other solutions before committing.

Comment: Yes, that is not uncommon for more "unique application" devices. The manufacturers usually build them in batches rather than setting up a continuous line. If this design is for a product, then your "due diligence" is to contact the manufacturer directly to see if this product is slated for the archives yet. They may even have a newer, as yet unpublished, version they intend to replace it with.

Comment: Also, if you plan on building 10,000 of these a year, it may well influence them to decide to keep the product alive longer if it is on the fence right now.

Comment: IN my experience, the sales people will bend over backwards to help you if it is a genuine product.

Comment: Just got an email from Melexis rep. The MLX10407 has EOL status and not is recommended for new designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are pretty specialized products and are not very likely to be used by a broad range of customers so stock at disties my not be as good an indication of status as usual. For example, the CS8190EDWFR20G is listed as active by Onsemi and the Melexis part may be okay for availability, depending on your expectations.

You will not be able to drive the air core movement directly from a micro- it requires two relatively high bipolar currents in quadrature, and typically with more compliance than the micro supply voltage. It's possible you could get it to work with PWM and two H-bridges rather than analog signals but that raises other issues such as EMI and you would have to evaluate the accuracy hit if you use voltage drive.

Comment: Thank you. The OnSemi part though is for Speedo frequency input, I need more freedom by sending data serially, albeit that can be tricked by generating a frequency - dirty solution but functional.

Comment: The F->V converter is separate but you'd need a DAC to use that particular chip by bypassing it.